# Computed column specification - minimum value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, minimum

I have a table in SQL Server and have a column that I want to calculate the minimum value from three other columns (Vendor1, Vendor2, and Vendor3).  I have figured out how to sum the values but can't figure out how to find the minimum value- I keep getting an error that an aggregate may not appear in a computed column.  Is there a simple way to figure this out?

Comment: Show us your statement (update your answer)

Comment: yes - there is a function MIN - show what you have tried.

Comment: @Randy you cant use that in a computed column.

Comment: can we see the code that's causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expresion

```
CREATE TABLE T
  (
     Vendor1 INT,
     Vendor2 INT,
     Vendor3 INT,
     MinVendor AS CASE
          WHEN Vendor1 < Vendor2
               AND Vendor1 < Vendor3 THEN Vendor1
          WHEN Vendor2 < Vendor3 THEN Vendor2
          ELSE Vendor3
        END
  )
```

But having columns `Vendor1 - 3` probably indicates that your table is not in [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MinOf3(@a int, @b int, @c int)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
 RETURN (SELECT MIN(a) FROM (
                            SELECT @a a UNION ALL
                            SELECT @b  UNION ALL
                            SELECT @c
                            ) T(a)
         )
END
GO

CREATE TABLE T(a1 int, a2 int, a3 int, a4 as dbo.MinOf3(a1, a2, a3))
```

Comment: Or `RETURN (SELECT MIN(a) FROM (VALUES(@a),(@b),(@c)) T(a))` if 2008+

Comment: BTW I +1 ed this as for more than 3 columns it probably works out much more manageable than `CASE` but scalar UDFs in computed columns will completely block any parallel plans for the table even if the column is not referenced. [Mentioned here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

MIN is as it says an aggreagate. It finds the minimum value of a column across all rows for a single column. It sounds like what you are trying to do is find the minimum in each row for across three columns. SQL does not have a built in function to do that, but it can be done with a simple CASE expression as Martin SMith has already shown.

You may also want to consider using a View rather than a Computed Column, which would allow you to do it this way as well.

```
SELECT     OtherColumn,
                          (SELECT     MIN(Vendor) AS Expr1
                            FROM          (SELECT     Vendor1 AS Vendor
                                                    UNION ALL
                                                    SELECT     Vendor2
                                                    UNION ALL
                                                    SELECT     Vendor3)) AS VendorMimum
FROM         Vendors
```